# Magento 2 graphql send createEmptyCart and addSimpleProductsToCart in same request

Tags: magento2, graphql

Can I create a cart and add the products to cart in same request? Maybe using something like variables to pass by the cartId.

Comment: describe some more detail, what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd need to create your own graphql endpoint.

For your case, if you want to implement that type of custom graphql call, you'd need to take a look at `vendor/magento/module-quote-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls`

specifically both graphql calls:

```
   type Mutation {
        createEmptyCart(input: createEmptyCartInput): String @resolver(class: "\\Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\CreateEmptyCart") @doc(description:"Creates an empty shopping cart for a guest or logged in user")
        addSimpleProductsToCart(input: AddSimpleProductsToCartInput): AddSimpleProductsToCartOutput @resolver(class: "Magento\\QuoteGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\AddSimpleProductsToCart")
```

then, the difficult part is to combine

`\Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\CreateEmptyCart` with `\Magento\QuoteGraphQl\Model\Resolver\AddSimpleProductsToCart` into your own custom resolver.

it is doable but challenging. The customisation duplicates a lot of code out of these 2 resolvers and I do wonder whether that is worth the try